# Prevent auto-pairing for certain devices (Bluetooth)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, audio, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I have a Early 2011 Macbook Pro 13" running OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite).

At work, I have a [Apple Magic Trackpad](https://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/) and an [Apple Wireless Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/keyboard/), both which use Bluetooth. When I get to work, my Mac automatically connects to both of them (if Bluetooth is on).

At home, I have a Belkin F8Z492-P Bluetooth Audio Adapter hooked up to my stereo (sorry, no product page available). If Bluetooth is on, my audio will automatically be routed to the Bluetooth adapter (which is something I rarely want).

How can I make OS X automatically connect to my trackpad and keyboard at work but not automatically connect to the bluetooth audio adapter at home?

Currently, I shut Bluetooth off when I get home, but I'd like to avoid toggling Bluetooth when I get home/when I get to work, since it is quite annoying to start typing on the wireless keyboard and have nothing happen, or not have audio when I get home.

If this is not possible, can I prevent OS X from switching my audio automatically when connecting to the Bluetooth audio adapter?

Comment: I'd rather not have to un-pair and re-pair it when I want to use it, since the actual adapter is in an inconvenient place.

Comment: Not only does it do this when the Macbook is asleep, it also opens iTunes (which I don't use), and there could be ~3 different devices connecting to the speaker when I switch it on, leading to the hilarious "who is hijacking my speaker?" game.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had the same problem and FINALLY found a workable solution. Run this in your terminal. After this you just need to manually connect to your bluetooth audio system.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DontPageAudioDevices 1
```

Comment: For clarity, your Mac will not auto-connect to audio devices but will continue auto-connecting to other devices, right?

Comment: Exactly, so for example my mac will still automatically connect to my keyboard and mouse but if I want to connect to my stereo I need to manually select it from the bluetooth list of devices.

Comment: I would be so delighted if this worked for me. Unfortunately, it does not! While this might have worked for earlier OSX versions, I am finding that on Sierra 10.12.16, it has no noticeable effect after setting the plist value as described above. I even confirmed the value after a reboot and it reported back as 1 via `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DontPageAudioDevices`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, and now I can't downvote the answer anymore. Gaah.

Comment: I want to do the reverse meaning I want my iPhone to get connected automatically to my mac over the Bluetooth for network sharing is that possible?

Comment: Correction: It started working after I restarted my computer today.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Not with this setting. It's for Bluetooth-connected audio devices. So it's better if you ask a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) and it doesn't work for me, even after a reboot.

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. On Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Worked just fine for me, on Catalina (10.15.6). Before I tested, I turned BT off and then on again.

Comment: Doesn't work in Big Sur

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Big Sur after 4 restarts and I can confirm a value of 1 when I do ```defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DontPageAudioDevices```

Answer (score 19):

Adding MAC address of a device to IngoredDevices disables auto connect of Bluetooth. To do so follow these steps:

1. disable Bluetooth.
2. find MAC address in DeviceCache with following command

   ```
   sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DeviceCache
   ```
3. add MAC address to IgnoredDevices

   ```
   sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist IgnoredDevices -array-add '<MAC ADDRESS>'
   ```
4. print contents of the file, you should see there MAC address which has been added in step 3

   ```
   sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist IgnoredDevices
   ```
5. restart your Mac
6. enable Bluetooth

This should work on Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: Will this prevent the device from being manually connected to?

Comment: Sadly, this gets reset if you have Apple BT devices connected via USB and turn on Bluetooth.

Comment: Can't get this to work. On Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: This actually works in Big Sur! Thank you! You solved the most annoying problem I had on Mac!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Big Sur after 5 restarts. I can confirm that the device's MAC address is returned with ```sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist IgnoredDevices```

Comment: This works a treat - just stops it autoconnecting but the device still shows up in the bluetooth devices list so it's easy to connect to it when you need! ⭐

Comment: Works for me w/ Jabra Elite Active 65t earbuds after restart on a Macbook Pro 15-inch 2019 running Big Sur 11.5 (20G71). This answer is preferred for me, as I have a different Bluetooth audio device that I *do* wish to automatically connect to my Macbook Pro. Now if only I could apply this setting to my iPhone...

Comment: Does not work on Ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 4):

I have Bluetooth headphones for which none of the previous solutions worked. By headphones were pretty cheap and I discovered that my Macbook Pro 2019's initial connection for auto-pairing was terrible (audio consistently skipped), but after disconnecting and reconnecting it was fine. I originally came to this post before Big Sur and back then adding my headphones’ MAC address to the list of IgnoredDevices (see [answer from Kiyose](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380909/336212)) worked. But after Big Sur (currently on 11.4), neither `DontPageAudioDevices` nor adding to `IgnoredDevices` worked for me. This could be due to the shoddy implementation of Bluetooth on my cheap headphones, probably not uniquely due to Big Sur. In fact, connecting to my headphones totally messed up the Bluetooth module to the point where it couldn’t be turned on/off, and none of the traditional solutions (e.g. reset bluetooth module, **Bluetooth** → **Debug**, delete `.plist` files, etc.), other than reboot, could fix it. Obviously didn't want to have to reboot my Mac every time I wanted to connect headphones. So I came up with this solution for Bluetooth devices that are so problematic that you need to disconnect *and* unpair every time. This solution requires [blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil).

1. Install `blueutil`:

```
homebrew install blueutil
```

2. Use [Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac) (or any similar application) → **Quick Actions** → **Run Shell Script** with workflow set to receive **no input** and work in **any application**. Create two scripts that contain `blueutil` commands to pair/connect and unpair/disconnect to your bluetooth device. Note I found I needed to include full path for Automator's shell to find `blueutil`, perhaps because it is not being run interactively. You can confirm your scripts are working by monitoring **System Preferences** → **Bluetooth** and using the **Run** button in Automator, before proceeding to the next step.

```
# pair/connect
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --pair <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_BT_DEVICE>
sleep 5
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --connect <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_BT_DEVICE>
```

```
# unpair/disconnect
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --disconnect <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_BT_DEVICE>
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --unpair <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_BT_DEVICE>
```

3. Set up keyboard bindings to the Automator quick actions with **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Services**. The new actions should be under **General** if you set to receive no input.

Now when you turn your bluetooth device on, simply use your keyboard shortcut to pair/connect. And when you're done, turn it off and run the disconnect/unpair action.

Comment: Thanks. blueutil path is maybe `/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil` now.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a long shot, but at home go into System Preferences > Sound > Output and manually select the Default option (Usually Speakers).

This means that OS X will re-prioritise so that when the Belkin F8Z492-P Bluetooth Audio Adapter becomes available, you'd rather use the default option.

Then, when you want to use it, select it via the AirPlay menu (if possible) because that doesn't affect OS X's priorities. If it is not available via the AirPlay menu then you will just have to manually switch forward and back with the System Preferences app, unless you feel like diving into some AppleScripting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my headphones always connecting to my mac.

I did the following:

- Install some helpers via brew

  - `blueutil`
  - `coreutils`
- Find the bluetooth device id via

```
blueutil --paired
```

- Create the following script and update **btid**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

btid="98-8e-79-00-8c-9f"

while true; do
  echo "wait for connect of $btid"
  blueutil --wait-connect $btid
  echo "disconnecting $btid"
  gtimeout 1s blueutil --disconnect $btid
done
```

- Make it executable via

```
chmod +x my_script.sh
```

- Run it via

```
./my_script
```