# How to prevent laptop to auto-connect to bluetooth speaker?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a MacBook Pro with Catalina. The laptop constantly connects with a  bluetooth speaker. How can I keep it disconnected by default without removing the pairing to that device or turning off bluetooth completely ?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer from a few years ago.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/226169/149366)

Comment: Turn the speakers off when not using them.

Comment: @Seamus The DontPageAudioDevices option I have tried and did not work for me.

Comment: @user3439894 I can't turn off the speakers as my wife or the kids may want to connect to them.

Comment: @Wolfgang have you found a solution?