# How to disable the "Your trackpad is wirelessly connected to this Mac" notification?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, dock, trackpad, magic-trackpad

So I have a 2019 Macbook Pro connected to a Caldigit TS3 Plus dock. Connected to that I have a Magic Trackpad 2 via USB cable (to charge it). It is a Bluetooth device. Every time I connected my MBP to this docking station I get this stupid notification:

[image: Your trackpad is wirelessly connected to this Mac]

And I can't for the life of me figure out how to disable this. There's no Bluetooth setting for the device. Clicking on "Settings" takes you to the Bluetooth System Preferences. There's nothing I can see under Notifications Systems Preferences that pertains to this.

Now I should also mention that I connect TWO different MBPs to this same docking station and it seems like only when I change laptops does this come up but I'm not 100% sure about that (as in, I'm not 100% certain it doesn't show up when I power the same laptop on or wake it up).

I'm actually shocked that a Google search for "Your trackpad is wirelessly connected to this Mac" (including quotes) has exactly 0 matches.

Comment: Have you looked at this existing question? :
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159548/prevent-auto-pairing-for-certain-devices-bluetooth

Comment: I want the trackpad to pair to the connected Macbook. I just don't want to be notified about it with something I need to acknowledge/dismiss.

Comment: My bad. You might try adapting gyf304's solution on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7533031 to your .plugin files. My macbook pro on El Capitan has one called multitouch. I'm no apple developper, so please proceed at your own risks. Always have a backup of everything before playing with these system files, and save a copy of the actual .plugin file in another folder before doing the terminal command.

Comment: @cletus did you find a solution?

Comment: @roydukkey You can probably just adapt my answer from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly/428990#428990 by adding a few extra conditions to the if statement. I am probably going to add support for the mouse/trackpad/keyboard messages to it.